# collective.tinymceplugins.embedly only shows embedly link button in toolbar

Tags: plone

I have installed collective.tinymceplugins.embedly and expected to see an embed button like here http://vimeo.com/40592731 but there is only an embed.ly link button which seems to just link to the video on the video providers site. I have activated the product unde quickinstall and added the API key. Is there another step to configuration?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:
https://github.com/collective/collective.tinymceplugins.embedly

> To use the Embedly plugin on your site, you need to provide an API key
>   (available from embed.ly). You can set the API key by going to Site
>   Setup -> Configuration Registry and setting the api_key value.

Be sure to do that.

Comment: Sorry I had done that. I have edited the question to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

whilst this is not answer to your question on how to get collective.tinymceplugins.embedly, this offers you an alternative solution: collective.embedly (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.embedly)

it also offers a tiny mce button and a settings dialow with more options (eg autoplay and thelike)